# Reshaping basket data frame for separating items in a basket

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I work with a data set of customers purchase baskets. Here is a sample of it:

```
  basket item quant
1      1    B     1
2      1    A     2
3      1    C     1
4      2    A     1
5      2    C     1
6      3    A     2
7      4    B     1
8      4    C     1
```

Here is the code for reproducing it:

```
input <- data.frame(
    basket = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4),
    item = c("B","A","C","A","C","A","B","C"),
    quant=c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1)
)
```

So in the first basket there are three items with specified quantities. I have  a custom function that only works with a specific format of input; We define a maximum basket size. Let's say it is 5. Now the input to that function should be like this:

```
  basket item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4 item_5
1      1      B      A      A      C    <NA>
2      2      A      C   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
3      3      A      A   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
4      4      B      C   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
```

I have been trying to do it using `dplyr` and `summarise` but have had no luck.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why would you want a column full with NA?

Comment: @Sotos This is just a smaple of data. There might be a basket with 5 items in it.

Comment: @AntoniosK No, basket size is determined by the number of items in the basket.

Comment: Since there is no basket with 5 in your example, I suggest you remove `item_5` as it can be confusing to others

Comment: I see your point. But the maximum basket size is part of the inputs to the problem so I thought it would be helpful to mention it.

Comment: I m still confused. So for this specific example would you want item_5?

Comment: Not for this specific example. But I wanted a solution that works for my entire data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

input[rep(1:nrow(input), input$quant),] %>% 
  group_by(basket) %>% 
  mutate(item2 = paste0('item_', row_number())) %>% 
  complete(item2 = paste0('item_', 1:5)) %>% 
  select(-quant) %>% 
  spread(item2, item)
```

which gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 6
>   basket item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4 item_5
>    <dbl> <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct> 
> 1     1. B      A      A      C      NA    
> 2     2. A      C      NA     NA     NA    
> 3     3. A      A      NA     NA     NA    
> 4     4. B      C      NA     NA     NA
> ```

Using the same logic, but with the `data.table`-package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(input)

input[input[, rep(.I, quant)]
      ][, .(basket, item, item2 = paste0('item_', rowid(basket)))
        ][CJ(basket = basket, item2 = paste0('item_', 1:5), unique = TRUE)
          , on = .(basket, item2)
          ][, dcast(.SD, basket ~ item2, value.var = 'item')]
```

Comment: I thought `expand` could be used to replicate the rows but I couldn't do it. It's weird there is no 'verse way of doing this specific operation

Comment: @Sotos Just realized that using `complete` is a better option.

Comment: hah...I don't think that item_5 is a requirement for this example. See my last comment on the question :) . If it is then yes `complete` comes to play here

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea via `tidyverse`. The tricks here are to replicate your rows based on `quant`, then remove the `quant` variable so it doesn't mess with your reshaping to wide data frame. After that you create a `new` variable that will deal with duplicates and of course finally `spread` to get the desired wide data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

df[rep(rownames(df), df$quant),] %>% 
 select(-quant) %>% 
 group_by(basket) %>% 
 mutate(new = paste0('item_', row_number())) %>% 
 spread(new, item)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 5
> # Groups:   basket [4]
>   basket item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4
>    <dbl> <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct> 
> 1     1. B      A      A      C     
> 2     2. A      C      NA     NA    
> 3     3. A      A      NA     NA    
> 4     4. B      C      NA     NA
> ```

Comment: I used this to replicate rows: `input %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(item = paste0(rep(item,quant), collapse = ",")) %>%
  separate_rows(item)` I guess it's slower than yours, but I'll leave it here in case someone has time to compare :)

Comment: @AntoniosK I avoid doing `rowwise` operations as much as possible as (as you said) they have a big cost in efficiency. But yes, that will work too

Comment: Agree. Another way could be something like this `input %>%
  group_by(id = row_number()) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(d = map(data, ~bind_rows(replicate(.$quant, ., simplify = FALSE)))) %>%
  unnest(d) %>%
  select(-id)`. Faster that `rowwise` I guess.